# getting Error: $sce:insecurl

Tags: angularjs

Im getting :  Blocked loading resource from url not allowed by $sceDelegate policy.  URL: //www.youtube.com/embed/61aM0DXpKkc on the following

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<style>
table, th , td  {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  padding: 5px;
}
table tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
table tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
</style>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
 <script src="app.js"></script>

<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl">

<table>
  <tr ng-repeat="x in names">
    <td>{{ x.Title }}</td>


    <td>
    <iframe class="youtube-player" ng-src="{{'//www.youtube.com/embed/' + x.URL}}" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

</td>


<td>{{ x.URL }}</td>
</tr>
</table>

</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
   $http.get("http://angular.webiflex.co.uk/connect.php")
   .then(function (response) {$scope.names = response.data.records;});
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

app.js

```
   var app = angular.module('plunker', [])
.config(function($sceDelegateProvider) {
   $sceDelegateProvider.resourceUrlWhitelist([
     'self',
     '*//www.youtube.com/embed/**'
   ]);
 });
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/L2kvZW8Uh45HeiGeaFtl?p=preview but am not sure what Im doing wrong as have used resourceUrlWhitelist.

Comment: check this: https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$sce/insecurl

Answer (score 6):

I managed to solve it http://plnkr.co/edit/L2kvZW8Uh45HeiGeaFtl

by adding

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http, $sce) {
   $http.get("http://angular.webiflex.co.uk/connect.php")
   .then(function (response) {$scope.names = response.data.records;});

  $scope.trustSrc = function(src) {
    return $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(src);
  };
});
```

and then

```
ng-src="{{trustSrc('//www.youtube.com/embed/' + x.URL)}}"
```